# how to install Windows Image Acquisition for development of image capture, in C#

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

How do I install WIA so I can make a C# project that connects to my USB camera, and then read and store an RGB frame?

Examples I saw in WIA tutorial seem to assume WIA is already installed.

I saw one CodeProject example of WIA code, that started with "using WIA;" but no explanation of how to install WIA.  It would not run because WIA is unknown.

I've tried adding a reference but cannot locate WIA.

Am using Visual Studio 2017 Pro on Windows 7 & 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIA is a COM library.

- Context-click References node under your Project node in Solution Explorer.
- Click the COM tab
- Find and check the item `Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0

Now you have a reference to WIA.  You should be able to follow along with your tutorials.